# FPDF table of contents and issues with page numbers

Tags: php, fpdf, tableofcontents

basically, I'd like to start the Table of Contents (toc) on page 2 and count each page number of the toc. After the toc has ended I would like to start with the main content. These page should be numbered, too.

In a nuthell:

- each page has to have a footer, except the cover page
- the first page which comes after the toc has to have the page number 4 instead of page number 1 (not like as in the example code below)

Source (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script73.php, filename is *toc.php*)

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_TOC extends FPDF {
    var $_toc=array();
    var $_numbering=false;
    var $_numberingFooter=false;
    var $_numPageNum=1;

    function AddPage($orientation='', $format='') {
        parent::AddPage($orientation,$format);
        if($this->_numbering)
            $this->_numPageNum++;
    }

    function startPageNums() {
        $this->_numbering=true;
        $this->_numberingFooter=true;
    }

    function stopPageNums() {
        $this->_numbering=false;
    }

    function numPageNo() {
        return $this->_numPageNum;
    }

    function TOC_Entry($txt, $level=0) {
        $this->_toc[]=array('t'=>$txt,'l'=>$level,'p'=>$this->numPageNo());
    }

    function insertTOC( $location=1,
                        $labelSize=20,
                        $entrySize=10,
                        $tocfont='Times',
                        $label='Table of Contents'
                        ) {
        //make toc at end
        $this->stopPageNums();
        $this->AddPage();
        $tocstart=$this->page;

        $this->SetFont($tocfont,'B',$labelSize);
        $this->Cell(0,5,$label,0,1,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);

        foreach($this->_toc as $t) {

            //Offset
            $level=$t['l'];
            if($level>0)
                $this->Cell($level*8);
            $weight='';
            if($level==0)
                $weight='B';
            $str=$t['t'];
            $this->SetFont($tocfont,$weight,$entrySize);
            $strsize=$this->GetStringWidth($str);
            $this->Cell($strsize+2,$this->FontSize+2,$str);

            //Filling dots
            $this->SetFont($tocfont,'',$entrySize);
            $PageCellSize=$this->GetStringWidth($t['p'])+2;
            $w=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin-$PageCellSize-($level*8)-($strsize+2);
            $nb=$w/$this->GetStringWidth('.');
            $dots=str_repeat('.',$nb);
            $this->Cell($w,$this->FontSize+2,$dots,0,0,'R');

            //Page number
            $this->Cell($PageCellSize,$this->FontSize+2,$t['p'],0,1,'R');
        }

        //Grab it and move to selected location
        $n=$this->page;
        $n_toc = $n - $tocstart + 1;
        $last = array();

        //store toc pages
        for($i = $tocstart;$i <= $n;$i++)
            $last[]=$this->pages[$i];

        //move pages
        for($i=$tocstart-1;$i>=$location-1;$i--)
            $this->pages[$i+$n_toc]=$this->pages[$i];

        //Put toc pages at insert point
        for($i = 0;$i < $n_toc;$i++)
            $this->pages[$location + $i]=$last[$i];
    }

    function Footer() {
        if(!$this->_numberingFooter)
            return;
        //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        //Select Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,7,$this->numPageNo(),0,0,'C'); 
        if(!$this->_numbering)
            $this->_numberingFooter=false;
    }
}
?>
```

Example

```
<?php
require('toc.php');

$pdf= new PDF_TOC(); 
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'Cover',0,1,'C');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->startPageNums();
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'TOC1',0,1,'L');
$pdf->TOC_Entry('TOC1', 0);
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'TOC1.1',0,1,'L');
$pdf->TOC_Entry('TOC1.1', 1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'TOC2',0,1,'L');
$pdf->TOC_Entry('TOC2', 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
for($i=3;$i<=80;$i++){
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,'TOC'.$i,0,1,'L');
    $pdf->TOC_Entry('TOC'.$i, 0);
}
$pdf->stopPageNums();
//Generate and insert TOC at page 2
$pdf->insertTOC(2);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

How can I do this? I can clarify the question/code if needed. I would appreciate any help to resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use TCPDF instead of FPDF? It has most of the same method calls and is more fully featured. In particular, adding a table of contents while keeping the page numbering sane is much more straightforward. If it's an option, I can provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Matt Raines already mentioned you have to switch to TCPDF to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a few simple steps.

1. When creating the PDF document content, leave an empty page (or pages) where your want the TOC to sit, e.g.:

   - `$this->pdf->AddPage('P','letter');`
   - `$this->pdf->AddPage('P','letter');`
2. Add your TOC contents to an array as you build the pdf content.

   - `$toc[] = ['label' -> "item", 'page' -> $pdf->PageNo()];`
3. After building all your content, save the current page number:

   - `$last_page = $pdf->PageNo();`
4. Set the page number to your TOC location:

   - `$pdf->page = 2;`
5. Create your TOC

   - (whatever)
6. IMPORTANT: Reset the page number to the saved value:

   - `$pdf->page = $last_page`